# Postgresql split column into rows

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 columns with a list of towns and I want to split the towns into rows

```
user 1 | [town1,town2,town3]
```

I want to split this into rows:

```
user 1 | town 1
user 1 | town 2
user 1 | town 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    username, 
    regexp_split_to_table(towns, E',') 
FROM yourTable
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/796567/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns are named `user_name` and `towns` you can do something like this:

```
select t1.user_name, t2.town
from the_table t1
  cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t1.towns,',')) as t2 (town)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on a_horse_with_no_name's answer, why not have something simpler like:

```
--Get some sample data
WITH test(username, town) as
(
select 'user 1', array['town1', 'town2', 'town3']
UNION
select 'user 2', array['town3', 'town2', 'town5']
)

--The following gives the results you are after.
SELECT username, unnest(town)

FROM test
```

I completely agree with using the unnest function, but I don't understand the reason for the cross join.

OP, it is very important what data type your "list" is stored as. Here I am assuming it is stored as an ARRAY. If it's stored as a string, then Rahul's answer will do the trick.